# Turning Banach space into a non-trivial Banach algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

Given a Banach space, how can we determine if we can turn it into a non-trivial (i.e., not all products are zero) Banach algebra or not?

Comment: What additional properties should a Banach algebra satisfy in order to count? $x\cdot y = 0$ is a Banach algebra structure on every Banach space.

Comment: Oh, yes. I should say that the Banach algebra is nontrivial.

Comment: Do you allow to change the norm to an equivalent one? Do you require a unit? Do you require multiplication to have norm one?

Comment: Yes, it is not an exact question, I am glad to see any interesting possibility. Maybe L^1(R) is a basic example, if we define its product point by point, it will not be a Banach algebra; but if we change its product with the convolution, it will be a Banach algebra with no unit, we can ask that whether we could change another product making it as a Banach algebra with unit. I guess no, but can not prove it. How about other Banach spaces?

Comment: A non-trivial situation that you can always define a product and guarantee a Banach algebra structure is when your Banach space is the double dual of a Banach algebra. Then you can always make it into a Banach algebra with a multiplication called left/right "Arens product". You can find more details about this in the paper by R. Arens, The adjoint of a bilinear operation, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 2 (1951)839-848.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you *can* turn any Banach space $A$ into a Banach algebra, by declaring all products to be $0$. Indeed, this is an algebra, since $r (x \cdot y) = (rx) \cdot y = x \cdot (ry) = 0$ and $(x+y) \cdot z = x \cdot z + y \cdot z = 0$ (here $x,y,z \in A$ and $r$ is scalar) (perhaps I omitted some condition, which but they are all trivially satisfied, with everything becoming $0$). It is associative since $(x \cdot y) \cdot z = x \cdot  (y \cdot z) = 0$. This can be done in either real or complex case. The arising Banach algebra (obviously) has no unit. This is a legit Banach algebra but not a very inspiring one.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should have a candidate of multiplicatiion "$\cdot$" in mind. Then, you can check the associativity of "$\cdot$", and if your Banach space is closed w.r.t. "$\cdot$". Usually, if "$\cdot$" is properly defined, associativity is not a big problem (convolution is already a rather complex case, but you can still show that.). But closeness is not that trivial. You may need to consider so-called multiplier of your Banach space w.r.t. "$\cdot$". Then the ***SMALLER*** space---all multipliers would form the pre-Banach algebra as you require (don't forget to complete it, or at least check completeness). You can refer to the paper: *A note on $\tau$-convergence,  $\tau$-convergent algebra and applications*, Topology and its Applications 159 (2012) 1433–1438, where an example of this process is displayed. Hopefully, this might be useful to you.